# Why does a query with extra left join work faster?

Tags: postgresql

Why does a query with extra left join work faster?

For the sake of this example, I have simplified my query as much as possible.

At first I was counting count_characteristic using a subquery,

```
---1
select count(1)
from product p
         JOIN price_amount_history pah ON pah.fk_product = p.id
         JOIN price_amount_history_item pahi ON pahi.fk_price_amount_history = pah.id
         LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(1), p.product_id
    FROM product p
             LEFT JOIN characteristics c ON c.fk_product = p.id
    WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL
      and p.category_id = 11937
    GROUP BY (p.product_id)

    UNION

    SELECT 0, p.product_id
    FROM product p
             LEFT JOIN characteristics c ON c.fk_product = p.id
    WHERE c.id IS NULL
      and p.category_id = 11937
    GROUP BY (p.product_id)
) t2 ON t2.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.category_id = 11937
  and t2.count <= 2
  and TIME >= date('2024-03-06 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
  and TIME <= date('2024-03-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
```

then I decided to speed it up and add this count as a column to the product table.

But my request became very slow!

```
    ---2
    select count(1)
    from product p
    JOIN price_amount_history pah ON pah.fk_product = p.id
    JOIN price_amount_history_item pahi ON pahi.fk_price_amount_history = pah.id
    WHERE p.category_id = 11937
    and p.count_characteristic <= 2
    and TIME >= date('2024-03-06 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
    and TIME <= date('2024-03-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
```

even such a stupid request is faster than the second one

```
    ---3
    select count(1)
    from product p
             JOIN price_amount_history pah ON pah.fk_product = p.id
             JOIN price_amount_history_item pahi ON pahi.fk_price_amount_history = pah.id
             LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT product_id, count_characteristic
        from product ppp
        WHERE ppp.category_id = 11937
    ) t2 ON t2.product_id = p.product_id
    
    WHERE p.category_id = 11937
      and t2.count_characteristic <= 2
      and TIME >= date('2024-03-06 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
      and TIME <= date('2024-03-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00')
```

How is this possible?

I even added an index on the count_characteristic column, but that didn't help
Unfortunately, I don’t know much about explain

but as I understand it, the third request first selects the required rows by time. And the second query does this later, so it has to analyze more rows

```
---2
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=3060636.37..3060636.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7068.335..7088.739 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  Buffers: shared hit=150490 read=1334647
  ->  Gather  (cost=3060636.15..3060636.36 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=7067.914..7088.726 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=150490 read=1334647
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=3059636.15..3059636.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7053.986..7053.992 rows=1 loops=3)
              Output: PARTIAL count(*)
              Buffers: shared hit=150490 read=1334647
              Worker 0:  actual time=7047.256..7047.262 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 21
"                  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"                  Timing: Generation 2.171 ms, Inlining 68.530 ms, Optimization 106.775 ms, Emission 57.632 ms, Total 235.109 ms"
                Buffers: shared hit=42640 read=454775
              Worker 1:  actual time=7047.174..7047.181 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 21
"                  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"                  Timing: Generation 2.193 ms, Inlining 68.669 ms, Optimization 109.575 ms, Emission 56.112 ms, Total 236.549 ms"
                Buffers: shared hit=45701 read=434311
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=26327.19..3059520.71 rows=46177 width=0) (actual time=5451.500..7047.791 rows=117524 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=150490 read=1334647
                    Worker 0:  actual time=5439.464..7043.009 rows=81808 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=42640 read=454775
                    Worker 1:  actual time=5448.454..7041.355 rows=109411 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=45701 read=434311
                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=26326.62..2056763.66 rows=11590 width=8) (actual time=5451.427..6983.315 rows=6764 loops=3)
                          Output: pah.id
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Hash Cond: (pah.fk_product = p.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=43400 read=1334401
                          Worker 0:  actual time=5439.376..6995.364 rows=5912 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=12147 read=454717
                          Worker 1:  actual time=5448.370..6975.255 rows=6372 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=12197 read=434186
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.price_amount_history pah  (cost=0.00..2028743.95 rows=644982 width=16) (actual time=5176.167..6661.754 rows=425624 loops=3)
"                                Output: pah.id, pah.cost_of_gods, pah.proceeds, pah.sell, pah.sum_amount, pah.""time"", pah.unix_time, pah.fk_product"
"                                Filter: ((pah.""time"" >= '2024-03-06'::date) AND (pah.""time"" <= '2024-03-07'::date))"
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 34821656
                                Buffers: shared hit=37173 read=1334401
                                Worker 0:  actual time=5171.435..6677.435 rows=459235 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=12116 read=454717
                                Worker 1:  actual time=5178.489..6662.681 rows=417151 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=12166 read=434186
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=26257.97..26257.97 rows=5492 width=8) (actual time=241.535..241.537 rows=4352 loops=3)
                                Output: p.id
                                Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 704kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=6167
                                Worker 0:  actual time=234.896..234.898 rows=2 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=1
                                Worker 1:  actual time=234.791..234.793 rows=1 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=1
                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.product p  (cost=347.49..26257.97 rows=5492 width=8) (actual time=229.927..234.451 rows=4352 loops=3)
                                      Output: p.id
                                      Recheck Cond: (p.category_id = 11937)
                                      Filter: (p.count_characteristic <= 2)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 38
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=6083
                                      Buffers: shared hit=6167
                                      Worker 0:  actual time=233.318..233.323 rows=2 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                      Worker 1:  actual time=234.678..234.682 rows=1 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_product__category  (cost=0.00..344.19 rows=13302 width=0) (actual time=1.209..1.209 rows=13197 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (p.category_id = 11937)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=82
                    ->  Index Only Scan using index_price_amount_history_item__fk_priceamounthistory on public.price_amount_history_item pahi  (cost=0.57..65.36 rows=2116 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=17 loops=20293)
                          Output: pahi.fk_price_amount_history
                          Index Cond: (pahi.fk_price_amount_history = pah.id)
                          Heap Fetches: 361565
                          Buffers: shared hit=107090 read=246
                          Worker 0:  actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=14 loops=5912
                            Buffers: shared hit=30493 read=58
                          Worker 1:  actual time=0.003..0.009 rows=17 loops=6372
                            Buffers: shared hit=33504 read=125
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=63
Planning Time: 0.576 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 65
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 6.627 ms, Inlining 150.690 ms, Optimization 360.611 ms, Emission 175.338 ms, Total 693.267 ms"
Execution Time: 7091.168 ms
```

```
---3
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=245735.29..245735.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1497.871..1514.001 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(9)
  Buffers: shared hit=223763 read=45044 written=776
  ->  Gather  (cost=245735.08..245735.29 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=1497.356..1513.989 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(9))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=223763 read=45044 written=776
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=244735.08..244735.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1474.135..1474.140 rows=1 loops=3)
              Output: PARTIAL count(9)
              Buffers: shared hit=223763 read=45044 written=776
              Worker 0:  actual time=1462.690..1462.696 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 28
"                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"                  Timing: Generation 4.864 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.395 ms, Emission 21.882 ms, Total 28.141 ms"
                Buffers: shared hit=71645 read=14834 written=254
              Worker 1:  actual time=1462.807..1462.811 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 28
"                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"                  Timing: Generation 4.848 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.428 ms, Emission 21.882 ms, Total 28.159 ms"
                Buffers: shared hit=73851 read=15254 written=270
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=26675.27..244732.98 rows=838 width=0) (actual time=38.596..1464.780 rows=117524 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=223763 read=45044 written=776
                    Worker 0:  actual time=27.257..1453.199 rows=117473 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=71645 read=14834 written=254
                    Worker 1:  actual time=27.139..1454.137 rows=119193 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=73851 read=15254 written=270
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=26674.70..226560.97 rows=210 width=8) (actual time=38.541..1356.409 rows=6764 loops=3)
                          Output: pah.id
                          Buffers: shared hit=116708 read=44763 written=773
                          Worker 0:  actual time=27.198..1339.452 rows=6639 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=36592 read=14735 written=253
                          Worker 1:  actual time=27.054..1350.788 rows=6930 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=37275 read=15178 written=269
                          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=26674.13..52591.95 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=37.776..56.118 rows=4352 loops=3)
                                Output: p.id
                                Hash Cond: (p.product_id = ppp.product_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=12394
                                Worker 0:  actual time=26.356..46.377 rows=4326 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=2035
                                Worker 1:  actual time=26.359..45.819 rows=4408 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=2051
                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.product p  (cost=347.52..26244.14 rows=5542 width=16) (actual time=1.929..12.955 rows=4390 loops=3)
"                                      Output: p.id, p.availible_last_date, p.category_id, p.early_load, p.last_update, p.product_id, p.show_on_page_last_date, p.time_last_update, p.title, p.fk_shop, p.count_characteristic"
                                      Recheck Cond: (p.category_id = 11937)
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=2061
                                      Buffers: shared hit=6167
                                      Worker 0:  actual time=1.935..14.718 rows=4362 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=2004
                                      Worker 1:  actual time=1.934..14.305 rows=4450 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=2020
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_product__category  (cost=0.00..344.19 rows=13302 width=0) (actual time=1.109..1.110 rows=13197 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (p.category_id = 11937)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=82
                                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=26257.97..26257.97 rows=5492 width=8) (actual time=35.530..35.532 rows=4352 loops=3)
                                      Output: ppp.product_id
                                      Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 704kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=6167
                                      Worker 0:  actual time=24.151..24.152 rows=1 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                      Worker 1:  actual time=24.108..24.109 rows=1 loops=1
                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                      ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.product ppp  (cost=347.49..26257.97 rows=5492 width=8) (actual time=22.061..27.316 rows=4352 loops=3)
                                            Output: ppp.product_id
                                            Recheck Cond: (ppp.category_id = 11937)
                                            Filter: (ppp.count_characteristic <= 2)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 38
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=6083
                                            Buffers: shared hit=6167
                                            Worker 0:  actual time=23.897..23.901 rows=1 loops=1
                                              Buffers: shared hit=1
                                            Worker 1:  actual time=23.914..23.916 rows=1 loops=1
                                              Buffers: shared hit=1
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_product__category  (cost=0.00..344.19 rows=13302 width=0) (actual time=1.232..1.232 rows=13197 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (ppp.category_id = 11937)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=82
                          ->  Index Scan using index_price_amount_history__fk_product on public.price_amount_history pah  (cost=0.57..1739.30 rows=39 width=16) (actual time=0.190..0.297 rows=2 loops=13056)
"                                Output: pah.id, pah.cost_of_gods, pah.proceeds, pah.sell, pah.sum_amount, pah.""time"", pah.unix_time, pah.fk_product"
                                Index Cond: (pah.fk_product = p.id)
"                                Filter: ((pah.""time"" >= '2024-03-06'::date) AND (pah.""time"" <= '2024-03-07'::date))"
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 143
                                Buffers: shared hit=104314 read=44763 written=773
                                Worker 0:  actual time=0.193..0.297 rows=2 loops=4326
                                  Buffers: shared hit=34557 read=14735 written=253
                                Worker 1:  actual time=0.187..0.295 rows=2 loops=4408
                                  Buffers: shared hit=35224 read=15178 written=269
                    ->  Index Only Scan using index_price_amount_history_item__fk_priceamounthistory on public.price_amount_history_item pahi  (cost=0.57..65.37 rows=2116 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.013 rows=17 loops=20293)
                          Output: pahi.fk_price_amount_history
                          Index Cond: (pahi.fk_price_amount_history = pah.id)
                          Heap Fetches: 361565
                          Buffers: shared hit=107055 read=281 written=3
                          Worker 0:  actual time=0.008..0.014 rows=18 loops=6639
                            Buffers: shared hit=35053 read=99 written=1
                          Worker 1:  actual time=0.007..0.012 rows=17 loops=6930
                            Buffers: shared hit=36576 read=76 written=1
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=82 read=1 dirtied=1
Planning Time: 1.135 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 86
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 12.703 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.691 ms, Emission 58.735 ms, Total 75.129 ms"
Execution Time: 1517.209 ms
```

Can I somehow influence the request?

Comment: Because of this `t2.count <= 2` in the WHERE condition of the first query, that "LEFT JOIN" isn't a left join at all. If you have a non-null filter in the WHERE predicate, you can type "LEFT' if you want, but what actually happens is an INNER join. So, adding an additional INNER join can speed things up because it can actually reduce the amount of data to crunch.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statements? You only showed the plan, not the execution of the plan

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks, I edited the question by doing "explain (analyze,verbose, buffers)"